# Unable to use knowledge and cases with guest access after Service SDK update to 212.0.x for iOS

Tags: ios, service, sdk

I am unable to use Knowledge and Cases after updating the iOS Service SDK from 210 to 212.0.x/iOS on both my dev SF account and a client's SF account. Both accounts work as expected on the previous SDK. I am testing with the Snapins SDK example to minimize any implementation issues caused by my code and cannot seem to get basic functionality working consistently; the behavior is inconsistent each time I launch the app in the iOS simulator. I am testing on the iPhone X simulator with iOS 11.3.

The initial launch after a clean install exhibits the following behavior:

Knowledge will show existing categories but the articles will not display; the loading indicator displays but no article appears. The are no error messages in the console. closing the knowledge view shows the follwing console output:

```
2018-04-04 11:22:34.190433-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1913691] Task <7FA9DBF0-F5EF-4913-B0FD-D5985B912D3F>.<11> finished with error - code: -999
2018-04-04 11:22:34.257937-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1913132] [analytics] Error ending a LiveAgent Logging Session: Error Domain=SCServiceCloudLoggingErrorDomain Code=404 "https://la1-c1-dfw.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/87649040-0975-4b36-abe0-83b3208a9ee3!1522866031639!6rYRW4LcfsQmhUvQi36Jk+BXgxs= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/87649040-0975-4b36-abe0-83b3208a9ee3!1522866031639!6rYRW4LcfsQmhUvQi36Jk+BXgxs=" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=https://la1-c1-dfw.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/87649040-0975-4b36-abe0-83b3208a9ee3!1522866031639!6rYRW4LcfsQmhUvQi36Jk+BXgxs= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/87649040-0975-4b36-abe0-83b3208a9ee3!1522866031639!6rYRW4LcfsQmhUvQi36Jk+BXgxs=}
2018-04-04 11:22:54.227595-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2018-04-04 11:22:54.228179-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
2018-04-04 11:23:01.391612-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2018-04-04 11:23:01.392077-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Cases shows the 'Contact Support' window with a loading indicator but no case UI displays. The following show up in the console:

```
2018-04-04 11:24:05.471462-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] [general] Could not create directory to store case data: (null)
2018-04-04 11:24:05.471579-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] [general] Could not retrieve Case data from '(null)'
2018-04-04 11:24:06.012451-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SCSPresentationBaseViewController: 0x7fa41ad60820>.
```

Closing the cases UI shows the following in the console:

```
2018-04-04 11:25:46.487436-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/chris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/07CBDE02-FD0D-4988-A53E-709B8200037F/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-04-04 11:25:46.488566-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1910924] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-04-04 11:25:46.635678-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1923444] [analytics] Error with LiveAgent Api Logging: {
    code = "SESSION_NOT_FOUND";
    description = "Session is uninitialized";
    eventType = "";
}
2018-04-04 11:25:46.834488-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1923444] [analytics] Error with LiveAgent Api Logging: {
    code = "SESSION_NOT_FOUND";
    description = "Session is uninitialized";
    eventType = "";
}
2018-04-04 11:25:46.894092-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1923444] [analytics] Error ending a LiveAgent Logging Session: Error Domain=SCServiceCloudLoggingErrorDomain Code=404 "https://la1-c1-dfw.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/3f3ea552-1c2d-4675-9e84-b08a637d78f3!1522866245924!uBjdVG8N1n5Q6lh4PAkNtHk0pho= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/3f3ea552-1c2d-4675-9e84-b08a637d78f3!1522866245924!uBjdVG8N1n5Q6lh4PAkNtHk0pho=" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=https://la1-c1-dfw.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/3f3ea552-1c2d-4675-9e84-b08a637d78f3!1522866245924!uBjdVG8N1n5Q6lh4PAkNtHk0pho= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/3f3ea552-1c2d-4675-9e84-b08a637d78f3!1522866245924!uBjdVG8N1n5Q6lh4PAkNtHk0pho=}
```

Closing the app crashes with the following:

```
2018-04-04 11:27:32.298265-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67221:1929927] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:]: URL is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b621e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f764031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113bd7975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f1a90f8 -[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:] + 89
    4   ServiceKnowledge                    0x000000010efa8617 __48-[SCSArticleCache cleanDiskWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 210
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115f71807 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115f72848 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115f77675 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1451
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115f7e3c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000115f7e0d2 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011649c1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011649bc4d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Launching again and testing knowledge show the categories but with a spinning loading indicator; the available articles do not display.

Closing the knowledge UI shows the following in the console:

```
-04-04 11:30:57.801108-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67376:1938389] Task <63F53648-FBEA-4C85-A5A6-34BC0D0FE82F>.<6> finished with error - code: -999
2018-04-04 11:30:57.842043-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67376:1938389] [analytics] Error ending a LiveAgent Logging Session: Error Domain=SCServiceCloudLoggingErrorDomain Code=404 "https://la1-c2-phx.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/40be0c88-68cb-4318-8a15-c71e37973d02!1522866572692!ZzeAxg0xN9Sr8vdooPXMmyj6Id8= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/40be0c88-68cb-4318-8a15-c71e37973d02!1522866572692!ZzeAxg0xN9Sr8vdooPXMmyj6Id8=" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=https://la1-c2-phx.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId/40be0c88-68cb-4318-8a15-c71e37973d02!1522866572692!ZzeAxg0xN9Sr8vdooPXMmyj6Id8= HTTP 404 for DELETE /chat/rest/System/SessionId/40be0c88-68cb-4318-8a15-c71e37973d02!1522866572692!ZzeAxg0xN9Sr8vdooPXMmyj6Id8=}
```

Cases behavior is the same as the initial launch behavior, the UI launches but no form displays, just the loading indicator.

Closing the app does not fail with an exception in this launch.

Launching a third time is again inconsistent. The knowledge UI appears but now no categories display; just a loading indicator. The console displays the following:

```
2018-04-04 11:33:49.354747-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67464:1946333] [ui] Could not find the root category "All" within the category group "Members".  Either it doesn't exist, or it has not been configured for use with the "KnowledgeArticleVersion" object type.
    Please refer to the Service SDK Developer's Guide for more information on configuring your organization.
    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/knowledge_cloud_setup.htm
2018-04-04 11:33:49.355070-0700 SnapinsSDKExample[67464:1946333] [ui] Could not find the root category "All" within the category group "Members".  Either it doesn't exist, or it has not been configured for use with the "KnowledgeArticleVersion" object type.
    Please refer to the Service SDK Developer's Guide for more information on configuring your organization.
    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/knowledge_cloud_setup.htm
```

Cases behavior is the same as above with similar logs in the console.

To reiterate, I have no issues with iOS SDK 210.2. and it is a straight up implementation using the Snapins example app with guest access. I have tried both my client's SF info and my SF dev account info with similar results.

Comment: Thank you for including so much detail in this question. Please refrain from pleas for help and stick to the facts. Other than that it's great. +1